# Set xyz-position of a single vertex

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

How do I do this? I want a little menu like when you move a whole object with an absolute x y and z value for the position of the vertex. I want to move a vertex to exactly be on (xyz) (1.5, 0, 1.5).

I Found this thread online but it's not clear what they mean and the shortcuts don't seem to work anymore on blender 2.8: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210302211800/https://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=19327) (what is the N-key panel and how do I open it?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is very easy to do.
You can adjust the vertex position in the *Transform panel*.
Just type the values into the x,y,z fields.

[image]

If you cannot see the *Transform Panel*, it's in the Sidebar.
Shortcut: <kbd>N</kbd>

[image]